# Is it possible to get the "last accessed date" of a storage account in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I know there is a policy for the lifecycle management that changes the tier depending on the last accessed date of a storage account (ref: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview?tabs=azure-portal#move-data-based-on-last-accessed-date-preview)) .

but I need to have it first on a report to present the data.

is it possible to get such?
maybe using log analytics or even resource graph explorer or any other tool as long as the date/data can be retrieved

NOTE: last accessed date is not the same as last modified

any help is well appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the "last accessed date" of a storage account in Azure?

As far I know, there is no **`"Last accessed date"`** property for the storage blob.

A possible solution you can add the date and time when your blob is tagged with the last access date and time it will be helpful to find out the last access date with time.

You can use the below command to add tags with last access using Powershell.

**Command:**

```
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -AccountName "xxx"
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context   

$lastAccessDateTime = Get-Date
$containerName = "xxx"
$blobName = "xxx" 
$tags = @{"LastAccessDateTime" = $lastAccessDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");}
Set-AzStorageBlobTag -Context $ctx -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Tag $tags
```

**Output:**
[image]

Now you an able to retrieve **`Get-AzStorageBlobTag`** command.

**Output:**

[image]

**References:**

1. [Use blob index tags to manage and find data on Azure Blob Storage - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=azure-powershell)
2. [lastaccesstime - Last Access Time of the Azure storage files - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419028/last-access-time-of-the-azure-storage-files) by Kevin B Burns.

Comment: the problem with this is that I don't "own" all these storage accounts so what if I add the tag, but the next day someone else access to this storage account, how could I check/change the data continuously ?

Comment: I have been trying to retrieve the same information. I would like to know if the client has used the files generated on my pipelines and also identify the files that weren't accessed a long time ago.