# Azure Storage - track last access time for files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We're working with tons of data stored as blobs in Azure blob storage that costs us a lot of money.

I'm sure that we can archive some of the files but for that, I need to gather the last access time of files and prove that they are sitting idle.

I want to get the last access time for the files for that matter.
I know that this option isn't directly available.
Log analytics isn't a good solution because it logs too much data and the very logging and saving of it costs a lot.

I know that the lifecycle rules engine allows me to enable last access time tracking fo use with rules . Is there ANY option where I can view that data, not through a rule ? log, blob properties, anything ?

Comment: As of now, the only way is `Azure lifecycle management policy` and use it to create rules based on the last access time of the blob. However, there is no direct way to view the last access time of a blob outside of a rule and there is no "Last accessed time or date" property for the storage blob.

Comment: damn. 
And theres no rule that i can see to actually write a log when a file is X days old right ? 
Just to move between tiers/archive.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no rule to write a log when a file is X days old. The only option is to move the file between tiers or archive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any option where I can view that data, not through a rule? Log, blob properties, anything?

According to [SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419028/last-access-time-of-the-azure-storage-files) by Kevin B Burns,

There is no direct way to view the last access time of a blob outside of a rule, and there is no "Last accessed time or date" property for the storage blob.

As of now, the only way to achieve this is [Move data based on last accessed time in Azure life cycle management policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#move-data-based-on-last-accessed-time).

**rule:**

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "name": "last-accessed-thirty-days-ago",
  "type": "Lifecycle",
  "definition": {
    "actions": {
      "baseBlob": {
        "enableAutoTierToHotFromCool": true,
        "tierToCool": {
          "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": 30
        }
      }
    },
    "filters": {
      "blobTypes": [
        "blockBlob"
      ],
      "prefixMatch": [
        "mylifecyclecontainer/log"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- You can view the last access time for blobs in Azure blob storage by enabling last access time tracking with the lifecycle rules engine. However, there is no direct option to view this data outside of using it with a rule.
- Unfortunately, there is no rule to write a log when a file is X days old. The only option is to move the file between tiers or archive it.

**Reference:**
[Optimize costs by automatically managing the data lifecycle - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview)